# How to configure Flutter specific paths for Dart and .pub-cache

Tags: flutter, dart, environment-variables, zshrc

I have both Flutter and Dart installed independently, because I need a specific version of Dart for some tasks.

This causes Flutter to complain about Dart path (on MacOS, but probably same on Linux):

> Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/3.2.4/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/francesco/flutter. Consider adding /Users/francesco/flutter/bin to the front of your path.

Is there a way for Flutter to configure path for Dart (and .pub-cache presumably) overriding the global variables?

My `.zshrc` below:

```bash
### DART
export PATH="$HOME/.pub-cache/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/flutter/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/dart/bin:$PATH"
```

See [a use case for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78259845/how-to-ensure-that-flutter-and-dart-projects-target-the-correct-pub-cache). See also this [discussion with Flutter team members](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/141527).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run different versions of Flutter on your system. You need to use FVM. And you can't override the global path. However you can downgrade or upgrade your SDK by the command

```
flutter upgrade
```

and

```
flutter downgrade <your version>
```

Comment: I'm familiar with fvm, but this is not answering (nor addressing) my question

Comment: I gave you the answer if you don't want to use FVM. 
"And you can't override the global path. How ever you can downgrade or upgrade your sdk by the comand"